# Moving Faucet Hole in Granite Countertop?

Tags: hole, granite

**EDIT 1/3: So I actually cancelled the order for the pictured sink, and bought an Elkay single-bowl sink with rounded corners. It fits perfectly in the existing opening, the wide edge might even allow for the hole not to have to be moved...BUT, I had no idea that the sink would have railings (or U-channel I guess it's called) on the bottom side, so those actually prevent the sink from fitting into the existing opening, even though the dimensions are perfect otherwise. Insert crying emoji. UGH.**

I would like to replace a two-bowl kitchen sink with a new single-bowl sink (both pictures included). The single-bowl sink dimensions are perfect for the existing opening, except for the faucet hole, which is off center currently, and would need to be centered (moved to the left) for the new sink. Is it possible to drill a new hole in the granite? I am not a DIY-er by any means and would be hiring someone, just wanted to know first if it's doable. Thank you. EDIT: I just saw that this board is for contractors and serious DIY-ers only, so I understand if my post is not acceptable (I was directed here from the Reddit sub).
[image]

[image: (]

Comment: This board is for people like you to ask questions.  Cutting a hole will not be hard with the right tools.  Just be sure the new sink will cover/hide the old hole and any other cuts.

Comment: If the new hole will overlap the old one, you ought to mention it to any contractors you contact.  They may have some additional words of wisdom.

Comment: Thank you! The new sink will cover the existing cutout fine, but I do think the new hole might overlap with the existing one. I will be contacting someone next week to come out and look at it.

Comment: Just a word of caution: pictured sink is rectangular, but current opening in counter top has round corners and asymmetrical back - as is this may result in poor end-user experience. You may want /need to make the opening more matching the sink.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I did take that into account and I believe it will fit, based on both sinks' measurements. I also have another option for the single-bowl sink, with rounded corners, like the existing one.

Comment: Kinda looks to me that in this case the pictured sink and prospective sink will not be compatible with retaining the faucet hole in its existing position—because the existing cutout will need to be expanded on the right half of the back edge, which would interfere with the existing hole.  The OP would need to be OK with a faucet at one of the back corners, using the plug from the new hole and some resin to plug the existing hole.  Maybe cover it up with a soap dish or sponge rack.  Also, the back flange on the prospective sink looks too deep for this counter.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, drilling a new hole is possible, just a matter of using the correct tools, or in your case hiring a contractor who knows how and has the correct tools. For a faucet hole that's usually a diamond hole-saw or a diamond core drill.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: Have a frank conversation with the contractor about what happens if the stone top cracks badly when cutting. Maybe it’s on their insurance; maybe it’s ’an  act of a deity’. And — just my opinion — I’d call stone counter specialists before I called a handyman or a general contractor.

Comment: OK, thank you! Not sure if a stone counter specialist would be willing to come out just to drill one hole, but I can try.

Comment: Getting them to come out: Pretty much a matter of paying the "roll the truck" charge plus the actual time cost of drilling the hole. If you're flexible on timing sometimes the roll-the-truck charge can be lower if they have another job in your area and can combine trips. The other option is to move the hole in the **sink**, and use a trim plate to cover the half-a-hole there, assuming you're overmounting this one. Or find another undermount sink that will do.

Comment: Thanks for the input, hopefully I can find someone to come out and evaluate everything!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are diamond blade hole saws that come in various sizes. Look for one that has the CARBIDE drill bit in the middle. Its more easy to control because the drill bit taps a hole in the granite before the hole saw touches it. If you can't find one any Tile shop should carry them.

Comment: Thank you for the info!